# Lightbox trigger event to click space or mouse left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have the follow script to load the lightbox,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.TESTER123').nivoLightbox({
            effect: 'fade',theme: 'default',
            beforeShowLightbox: function(){
                $('.TESTER123').hide()
            },
            afterHideLightbox: function(){
                $('.TESTER123').show();    
            },
            beforeHideLightbox: function(){
                var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 1 });
                jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-content").trigger( e );

            }
        });

    });
```

in the beforeHideLightbox function, I want to to generate a mouse left click event or space key press event so that when I close the lightbox window the video should pause playing, currently it keeps playing in the background. So I want to genenrate 1 of these two events inside the video frame that is the .nivo-lightbox-content or in center of the screen since the video will always be at the center.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation only on IE. on other browser it will automatically stop the video when lightbox closes or removed.

For IE, if it is a custom flash player you should create a function inside flash player to stop the video and trigger that function inside flash player using js.

If you are embedding youtube player, you cannot use direct embedding code. you should go for youtube api, so that you can control the player using js.

Comment: I am having this problem on all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the plugin nivo lightbox. When you click outside the video container is not removed from the page, instead it just fades out, so why the video is playing inside the faded out div.

Something wrong with plugin, since its compressed unable to show which line. Instead you can use plugin like this http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: if I am not asking for too much can you give me a working example of youtube video on colorbox on JSFiddle. Because I am not able to get it working.

Comment: wordking example is already there on the link i have supplied.. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

click on Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube) link on the page